# How to select the specific datas from the Dataframe after being used value_couts()?

Tags: python

I used python to read a file which contains the baby's names, genders and birth-years. Now I want to find out the names which are used both by boys and girls. I used `value_counts()`to get the appearance times of each name, but now I don't know how to extract the names from all the names.
Here is my codes:

```
def names_both(year):
    names = []
    path = 'babynames/yob%d.txt' % year
    columns = ['name', 'sex', 'birth']
    frame = pd.read_csv(path, names=columns)
    frame = frame['name'].value_counts()
    print(frame)
    """if len(names) != 0:
        print(names)
    else:
        print('None')"""
```

The frame now is like this:

```
Lou          2
Willie       2
Erie         2
Cora         2
            ..
Perry        1
Coy          1
Adolphus     1
Ula          1
Emily        1
Name: name, Length: 1889, dtype: int64
```

Here is the csv:

```
Anna,F,2604
Emma,F,2003
Elizabeth,F,1939
Minnie,F,1746
Margaret,F,1578
Ida,F,1472
Alice,F,1414
Bertha,F,1320
Sarah,F,1288
Annie,F,1258
Clara,F,1226
Ella,F,1156
Florence,F,1063
...
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you add a small extract of your csv?

Comment: @ndclt Of course, Here you go.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are for counting the number of names given both to girls and boys:

```py
common_girl_and_boys_names = (
    # work name by name
    frame.groupby('name')
    # count the number of sex given for the name and keep the one given to both sex, this boolean will be put in a column call 0
    .apply(lambda x: len(x['sex'].unique()) == 2)
    # the name are now in the index, reset it in order to get the names
    .reset_index()
     # keep only names with the column 0 with True value
    .loc[lambda x: x[0], 'name']
)
final_df = (
    # keep only the names common to boys and girls (the series build before)
    frame.loc[frame['name'].isin(common_girl_and_boys_names), :]
    # sex is now useless
    .drop(['sex'], axis='columns')
    # work name by name and sum the number of birth
    .groupby('name')
    .sum()
)
```

You can put those lines after the `read_csv` function. I hope it is want you want.

Comment: Great! It works well. Appreciate a lot. But I need some time to fully understand the code. Anyway, Thanks a lot!